# site working on server, but not in XAMPP - ( Notice: A session had already been started and Notice: Undefined variables )

Tags: php, xampp

I'm modifying a script i found which checks if it is installed or not and

-if yes it displays the login screen

-if not it displays the installation screen.

It works fine when installed online but not in XAMPP

In XAMPP it installs OK, but when going to the admin root the install screen is shown and the bellow the following.

> Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\testa\admin\admin_config.php on line 2
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: dbhost in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testa\main_admin.php on line 17
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: dbuname in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testa\main_admin.php on line 17
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: dbpass in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testa\main_admin.php on line 17
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: dbname in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testa\main_admin.php on line 18

I don't get it why it works on the web server and not in XAMPP....you guys have any ideas???

Here is the code from the relevant files

config.php

```
<?php
$dbhost="localhost"; //It is usually "localhost"

$dbuname="user";     //Database Username

$dbpass="pass";          //Database Password

$dbname="test";     //Database Name
?>
```

admin/index.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

if (isset($_REQUEST["uname"]))
    {
    $uname=$_REQUEST["uname"];
    $pass=$_REQUEST["pass"];
    include('../config.php');
    $db=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuname, $dbpass);
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $db);
    $check_security=mysql_query("select * from settings where admin_id='$uname' and password='$pass'", $db);

    if ($rec=mysql_fetch_row($check_security))
        {
        header('Location: index.php');
        $_SESSION['testa']="testa";
        }
    else
        header('Location: index.php');
    include('../main.php');
    }
else
    {
    include('admin_config.php');

    if (!isset($_SESSION['testa']))
        {
        echo ('<script language="JavaScript"> 
        <!-- 
        function CheckForm(formID) { 
        if (formID.uname.value == "") { alert("' . _ADMIN_ENTER_USERNAME . '"); 
        formID.uname.focus(); return false; } 
        if (formID.pass.value == "") { alert("' . _ADMIN_ENTER_PASSWORD . '"); 
        formID.pass.focus(); return false; }        
        return true; 
        } 
        //--> 
        </script> ');

        echo ('<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<form method="POST" action="index.php" onSubmit="return CheckForm(this);" autocomplete="off">
    <div align="center">
        <table width="250" border="1"  height="118" dir="' . $rtl_input . '"><tr>
            <td height="22" colspan="2">

    <p align="center"><font face="Tahoma" color="#FFFFFF"><span style="font-size: 9pt"><b>' . _ADMIN_SYSTEM_ALERT . '</b></span></font></td></tr><tr>
                <td height="31">

    <p align="' . $align . '"><font face="Tahoma" color="#FFFFFF"><span style="font-size: 9pt">' . _ADMIN_USERNAME . ':</span></font></td>
                <td height="31">

    <p align="left"><input type="text" name="uname" dir="ltr" size="20"></td></tr><tr>
                <td height="31">
                <p align="' . $align . '"><font face="Tahoma" color="#FFFFFF">
                <span style="font-size: 9pt">' . _ADMIN_PASSWORD . ':</span></font>
                </td><td height="31">
                <p align="left">
    <input type="password" name="pass" dir="ltr" size="20"></td></tr><tr>
                <td colspan="2" valign="bottom" height="38">
    <p align="center"><font face="Tahoma"><span style="font-size: 9pt"><input type="submit" value="' . _ADMIN_ENTER . '" name="B1"></span></font></p>
    </td></tr></table>
    </div>
</form>');
        }
    else
        {
        echo ('blahblahblah.................blah');
        }
    }
?>

</body>

</html>
```

main_admin.php

```
<?php

include('config.php');

include('jdf.php');

$db=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuname, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $db);
$result=mysql_query("select * from settings where id = '1'", $db);

if (!$result)
    {
    include('language/farsi.php');

    echo ('<html dir="rtl">');

    include('header_admin.php');

    echo ('<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JAVASCRIPT> 
    function dosubmit() { 
    document.forms[0].action = "users.php" 
    document.forms[0].method = "POST" 
    document.forms[0].submit() 
}</SCRIPT><script language="JavaScript"> 
        <!-- 
        function CheckForm(formID) { 
        if (formID.admin_id.value == "") { alert("' . _ADMIN_INSTALL_ENTER_USERNAME . '"); 
        formID.admin_id.focus(); return false; } 
        if (formID.password.value == "") { alert("' . _ADMIN_INSTALL_ENTER_PASSWORD . '"); 
        formID.password.focus(); return false; } 
        if (formID.password_confirm.value == "") { alert("' . _ADMIN_INSTALL_ADD_USER_ENTER_CONFIRM_PASSWORD . '"); 
        formID.password_confirm.focus(); return false; } 
        if (formID.password_confirm.value !== formID.password.value) { alert("' . _ADMIN_INSTALL_ADD_USER_PASSWORD_AND_CONFIRM_NOT_MATCH . '");
        formID.password.focus(); return false; } 
        return true; 
        } 
        //--> 
        </script> ');
    ///////////////////////

    echo ('<br /><br /><br /><br /><form method="POST" action="../install/" onSubmit="return CheckForm(this);"><div align="center">
                <table border="1" width="600" dir="rtl">
        ******************************************************
************************************blahblablah*************************************
    </table>
</div>
            </form>
            ');

    die();
    //////////////End form

    }
else
    {
    $rec=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $system_language=$rec[3];
    include('language/' . $rec[3] . '.php');

    if ($rec[4] == 1)
        echo ('<html dir="rtl">');
    else
        echo ('<html>');
    $result_rtl=mysql_query("select * from settings where id = '1'", $db);
    $rtl_array=mysql_fetch_row($result_rtl);

    if ($rtl_array[4] == 1)
        {
        $system_align=$align="right";
        $system_rtl_input=$rtl_input="rtl";
        }
    else
        {
        $system_align=$align="left";
        $system_rtl_input=$rtl_input="ltr";
        }
    include('header_admin.php');
    }
//////////////bg
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

ah got it,  You must be using the same `database name` form the server.

You must create a new table in `phpmyadmin` and copy all the tables form server database to xampp database and change the `dbname` `dbuname` `dbupass` accordingly.

**EDIT:**

And one more thing if you r installing the site on xampp again then remove config.php

Because the cms must be checking the config.php first then if found it establishes the connection to the db. where in this case there is no db found and the output is sent. which generates the errors for session start.